# How can I do select count(*) with "group by" in supabase-js?

Tags: reactjs, group-by, supabase

How do I write a "group by" query in supabase-js?

In traditional SQL it would look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), PLAYER FROM GAMES GROUP BY PLAYER
```

Using React and supabase-js, my code so far is like this:

```
    const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('games')
        .select('count(*), player')

        // I need something like this: .groupBy('player')
```

How can I do group by?

Answer (score 4):

A workaround is to [create an sql view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html)

```
create view player_games as SELECT COUNT(*) total, PLAYER FROM GAMES GROUP BY PLAYER
```

and you can then query player_games it as you would query a regular table

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can only be done by using the [RPC](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/rpc) (PostgreSQL functions).

- Unfortunately, I think this is the only way so far - but maybe this can be changed in the future.
- With the current *supabase-js SKD's* you can only count rows with [.match()](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/match) method. But this will count occurrence of every row that matches the criteria—it won't group them (so you can't use aggregate functions on them after)